# Error con RSS al llamar datos

Tags: php, rss

Tengo un script el cual lista los audio de una canal en Ivoox, pero tengo dos problemas, uno es que no me trae los audios y tampoco me trae la imagenes. Por el momento el cada audio tiene la misma imagen, pero tienen pensado cambiarlas.

Este es el script

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$rss = simplexml_load_file('https://ar.ivoox.com/es/espodcast-coe-global_fg_f1624731_filtro_1.xml');
echo '<h2>'. $rss->channel->title . '</h2>';    
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
?>
<img src="<?=$item->image-url;?>"><br>
<a href="<?=$item->link;?>"><?=$item->title;?></a>
<p><?=$item->description;?></p>
<p>
<audio controls>
<source src="<?=$item->enclosure;?>" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio> 
</p>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>

<?php
var_dump($item)
?>

object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (6) { ["title"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (0) { } ["link"]=> string(100) "https://www.ivoox.com/193-cristian-castellon-martin-lucca-daniel-lucca-audios-mp3_rf_39489123_1.html" ["enclosure"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { ["url"]=> string(92) "http://www.ivoox.com/193-cristian-castellon-martin-lucca-daniel-lucca_mf_39489123_feed_1.mp3" ["type"]=> string(10) "audio/mpeg" ["length"]=> string(8) "44400845" } } ["description"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (0) { } ["pubDate"]=> string(31) "Tue, 06 Aug 2019 07:05:06 +0200" ["guid"]=> string(29) "http://www.ivoox.com/39489123" }`
```

Agradezco de antemano!

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos un `var_dump($item);`? ¿Seguro que estás buscando en la parte adecuada del XML?

Comment: Lo tuve que editar porque no entraba en los comentarios

Comment: Analiza bien tu objeto y verás que en él no hay ninguna clave llamada `image-url` y en ninguna clave hay url alguna a archivos de imagen. En cuanto al audio, parece que se encuentra en la clave `url` de `enclosure`, podrás acceder a él haciendo algo así: `$item->enclosure->url`

Comment: Si y estoy notando que mas bien es para agregar en una url y redireccionar, iba usar `crul` como altenativa, pero no logre mucho... tendria que tratar de volver a hacerlo

Comment: `cURL` es mucho más potente. Si el sitio tiene forma de devolverte los datos vía `cURL` sería ideal. Cualquier dificulta, plantéala aquí y te ayudaremos.

Comment: Si voy a cambiar todo otra vez. Muchas gracias!